# Dataset containing countries ISO codes and images of their borders

Tags: dataset, gis, openlayers, geography

Looking for a dataset which would contain all countries with images of their borders without any text data on it.

This is closest to what I want https://www.geoboundaries.org/index.html#tabs1-css

Problem is that these images contain frame and text around country borders:
[image]

This could be cut if it always had same dimensions but unfortunately these images differ a lot. Where do I find this kind of dataset?

Comment: Do you want images or vector data?

Comment: You could produce and style your own outlines using publicly accessible vector data and a mapping client such as OpenLayers https://codesandbox.io/s/vector-layer-forked-bx2pi1?file=/main.js

Comment: @Mike could you post full answer so I can accept it? Your sandbox pretty much solves the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All credit goes to @Mike, who has commented my original question.

After little tweaks this gets the job done:

https://codesandbox.io/s/vector-layer-forked-bx2pi1?file=/main.js